# how to link a library to an executive file

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have a question about an executive file.

I got an executive files from another linux server,but the environment wasn't the same.

It's lack of libjemalloc.so.1. What could I do to let the executive file link to libjemalloc.so.1.

BTW,if I execute the file ,the error message is "error while loading shared libraries: libjemalloc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable pointing to the directory where you have kept the  libjemalloc.so.1. shared library file and then run the executable binary it will get the reference. 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="PATH TO SHARED LIBRARY"

Comment: After following your suggestions , it works!
Thanks!